# Program to select N integers with constraints

Tags: optimization, math

I need to write a program which takes 4 inputs as follows

- **N**     = The number of integers to be generated **(10 < N < 10000)**
- **Start** = The minimum value of the integers **(100 < Start)**
- **End**   = The maximum value of the integers
- **Step** = The minimum difference between any two integers **(100 < Step)**

and generates N integers within the range **[Start,End]**

I shall call the generated integers as **GI**

They are subjected to the following constraints-

- **Every GI must be unique**
- **The difference between any 2 GIs must be at least equal to the "Step" value**
- **No GI must be a linear combination of any of the other GIs**

by linear combination, I mean

```
GI[i] != a1*GI[1] + a2*GI[2] + a2*GI[3] + ... an*GI[n]
where n!=i for any n,i within [1,N] and {a1,a2,a3...an} are some integers
and != means 'Not equal to'
```

What is a good (if not the best) method to code this?

I have thought of one algorithm to find primes within that range using [Atkin's sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin). Now if the number of primes is larger than N, then proceed with checking linearity condition, else generate random numbers satisfying step condition till N values are reached and then proceed with checking.... This doesn't sound that much elegant to me. So I am interested in better methods

Comment: Have sketched out some algorithms yourself yet? Your question seems a lot like a homework assignment. Show us what you've done.

Comment: Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve with this algorithm? It is difficult to assess if it is a good or bad algorithm without knowing the problem it is trying to solve. Or is this as @COMEFROM asked, just a home work assignment for Algorithms 101. In which case I'll say what you mother would no doubt say, you won't learn by copying some one else's answer :-)

Comment: @CormacMulhall I couldn't find any online reference to this kind of problem. Actually, this problem sprung up during my undergrad research. I have thought of one algorithm to find primes within that range using atkin's sieve. Now if the number of primes is larger than N, then proceed with checking linearity condition, else generate random numbers satisfying step condition till N values are reached and then proceed with checking.... This doesn't sound that much elegant to me. So I am interested in better methods

Comment: @gnat I am sorry but this is a desperate attempt to get a solution. For the method which I am currently using, see my reply to ComacMulhall

Comment: @COMEFROM For the method which I am currently using, see my reply to ComacMulhall

Comment: You might ask Math.SE if there is any way to satisfy your linearity condition without primes.

Comment: The "no linear combinations" requirement is the only non-trivial one that makes this question potentially interesting and understandably non-googleable. Until I got to that part I was in complete agreement with the other comments that this looks like a request to do your homework for you. I'd highly recommend rewriting the question to focus on that requirement, and introduce n/start/end/step at the end so they look like the minor details they are (or I could rewrite it for you, if you agree this change would not misrepresent your question).

Comment: @Ixrec Please understand this is not my homework, This is a genuine problem which came during my undergrad research. Yes I will try rewriting the question focussing on the linear combination constraint, But That is more suitable for Mathematics or Mathoverflow than here. But If there is anyone here who could solve math program problems like in [Project Euler] (https://projecteuler.net/), Kindly Guide me.